# Insert pages of pdf in document

Tags: color, pdfpages

I a pdf file that contains the "first" page of each chapter, 26 in total,  of a book I wrote. I use `\includepdf[pages=1]{foo.pdf}` for the cover  and works fine. But, when I go the chapter 1 and use `\includepdf[pages=2]{foo.pdf}` I get an empty page. What is wrong? My code:

```
\documentclass{book}      
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}      
\usepackage{booktabs,newtxtext,newtxmath,multirow}      
\usepackage{ltablex}      
\usepackage{amssymb}        
\usepackage{mathabx}      
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphics}      
\begin{document}  
\includepdf[pages=2]{portadas}  
\pagecolor{lilita}  
\includepdf[pages=4]{portadas}  
\include{i_}  
\includepdf[pages=5]{portadas}  
\include{u_}  
\end{document}
```

If I use `\pagecolor{...}` command I obtain blank pages:
[example using \pagecolor](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JqhuV-AYkADuTYcy-qyYLW6IsknikaXo)

but, if I drop that command, I obtain the first pages:
[example without \pagecolor](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MjOhWJUKzSY6Y2S9BpDHcyiZqIIO3lEN)

This is the 'portadas' file:
[portadas.pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LKljeDD-yEDmEeMIk1yWm1n8GNwd21J8)

I want the pages to have color. How do I acomplish that?

Comment: Is the 2nd page of `foo.pdf` blank?

Comment: No. In this "foo.pdf" I generated the cover page and the first page of each chapter using an Adobe's program. This foo.pdf contains 26 pages. But "calling" the corresponding page for chapter 1  I obtain a blanck page, which I know is not blanck in the pdf. And so forth for the rest of the chapters.

Comment: Try to insert with smaller size to see if the problem comes from some non free space to insert.

Comment: I scaled the pdf: `\includepdf[pages=1,scale=.5]{foo.pdf}`. Same results.

Comment: So, please, try to edit your post and show us a minimal code and provide your pdf. Then, we can try to compile it and compare.

Comment: To compile your code we need the `portadas` file.

Comment: I just added the "portadas" file. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Without `\pagecolor` it is good.

Comment: Known problem covered under 'Pitfalls' in the `pdfpages` manual. Easy fix.

Comment: Off-topic: Consider using `graphicx` rather than `graphics`.

Comment: I might also mention that \includegraphics has an undocumented [page-...] option.  (I discovered it by looking at the \pdfpages source.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
\pagecolor{white}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

Ref.: section 2.5 of `pdfpages` manual p. 11.

Note that the colour chosen doesn't matter. You can change it as much as you like after and specify anything you like here. But you must specify a colour before loading `pdfpages`.